# Looking for faster or better method to select the nth child of an XML node using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, css-selectors

Here is my code:

```
var CDs=$(xml).find("CDs");
var NthChild = $(CDs).find("CD:nth-child(index)"); // nth-child 0th element starts at 1
```

I'm using the find method here; I have to specify the child node name, which is noted as "CD".  Is there are a faster or shorter method, perhaps one that doesn't need me to specify the name of the child node (i.e. "CD") to find the nth child node?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I found a format that doesn't need to specify the child node by name:

```
var NthChild = $(CDs).children(":nth-child(index)");
```

Comment: You can also traverse your XMLDocument with XPath-expressions who are faster and more powerfull than CSS-selectors/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is how I factored the code, prior to jquery.  However, I am trying to maximize browser compatibility.  I suppose not every line of code has to be refactored into a jQuery equivalent, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(xml).find("CDs CD").eq(index);
```

According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

> Because :eq() is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :eq() cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   $("your-pure-css-selector").eq(index) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(xml).find("CDs CD:eq(0)")
```

Put the desired index inside of the parens following `eq`

Or, if `CD` elements only live under `CDs` and you aren't worried about getting the wrong ones:

```
$(xml).find("CD:eq(0)")
```